# key_events of GUI widget and stdin

Tags: user-interface, redirect, event-handling, wxpython, stdin

I am quite confused about the stdin and the key_events of GUI widget.

Usually in my mind, I thought stdin is the ordinary way to get the keyboard input for a process. E.g., If I have a process, then I could use stdin to have the keyboard inputs. And this is usually used to make I/O direction for the subprocess to get keyboard inputs. E.g., I could make subprocess.Popen(stdin=PIPE)

On the other hand for GUI, I am using wx.TexCtrl or py.Shell.shell, to catch the key events, like inputs.

So I am quite confused here, if I have a GUI or pyShell running, when I am typing via the keyboard, is it via the stdin or via the GUI key event catching system? If via the GUI key events system, how can I get the keyboard stdin? Can I still simply redirect the keyboard inputs to my child process (inside the GUI) as the ordinary non-GUI programming?

Thanks a lot for any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type, the input comes from the GUI event mechanism, *not* from stdin. You asked how to get the "keyboard stdin", and the answer to that is the same as for any other type of program: you read it (but it will almost certainly be empty). It's important to realize that the GUI probably doesn't have a stdin if it was started by double-clicking on an icon on the desktop.

And no, you can't "redirect keyboard inputs to [your] child process", if I understand your question. Stdin really has absolutely nothing to do with GUIs at all. How keyboard input is read via a GUI is completely disconnected from stdin.

Comment: Bryan, thank you very much for your answer. I up-click your answer first. Just a few questions based on your answer. If sys.stdin still exists, can I give input via it in a GUI program, from file or from keyboard? If I start wxPython GUI from python in the bash, is the sys.stdin at the bash window? Also, from what you described, it seems there is no sys.stdin usage for a GUI, However, the sys.stdout sometimes could be useful to print out the information on a textctrl widget. So the pyCrust or GUI based shell, actually has only used sys.stdout, leaving sys.stdin no use, am I right?

Comment: @pepero: no, you can't give input to stdin via the keyboard, but with the right amount of coding you could pipe some data into your gui with something like `"echo hello" | mygui`. I can't think of any use cases where that would be worthwile though.

Comment: I'd imagine one usecase is to insert a GUI viewer of data passing through a pipe; especially in a nontrivial pipechain. Threading might be appropiate if your input stream is high-capasity; as GUIs APIs typically are designed to be asyncronous event handlers; meaning your data may buffer faster then your UI updates.